# session cookie is not being send by server

Tags: php, session, cookies

Moving to an other server with my website, i'am facing serious problems with the php sessions. As i can inspect it from my chrome dev console, cookies are send when i use `setcookie()`, but using `session_start()` leaves no trace of a cookie send by to server to the browser.

Having the site on a subdomain, i already tried to give the real subdomain:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'real.subdomain.net');
session_set_cookie_params( 0, "/", "real.subdomain.net", false, false);
```

I found some people with the same problem, who where able to solve theres by changing the session save path:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
```

Neither works that for me. I do not get any errors or notice.

`phpinfo()` and the session section leaves no clue, i looks just like the one of anybody else.

---

**Workaround**

I found a little workaround for this case, where "normal" cookie are working but not the session cookie:

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) ) {
    session_id($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
    session_start();
} else {
    session_start();
    setcookie(session_name(), session_id());
}
```

Comment: and do you have a `/session` directory above the document root by 1 level, and is it writable?

Comment: `session_set_cookie_params( 0, "/", "real.subdomain.net", false, true);` to set the HTTPonly flag. (recommended)

Comment: @lolka_bolka indeed i do.

Does the "Cache-Control" parameter has any effects on cookies?

Comment: What does the [session parameters tell you](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php)?

Comment: @Martin Not very much. _domain_, _secure_ and _httponly_ are empty, _lifetime_ is '0' and _path_ is '/'. It seams like `session_set_cookie_params` has no effect on that values.